# How to write in French script mt font

Tags: fonts, french

How can I print an output in French Script MT font style using LaTex, what is the package to use? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the font in your system you can use `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{French Script MT}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or you can compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: Actually, my goal is to use the command \frmt in math mode. Example is: $\llcurly_\frmt {M}$. That is, the M which should be in French Script MT font style, is to appear as a subscript of the order symbol \llcurly. I ran the code but the output M did not show as the required font style. Any workable solution please?

Comment: you can try define your command `\frmt` with  `\newcommand{\frmt}[1]{\mathit{#1}}`