# How to write an alphabet in French Script font style within a document with another font style

Tags: fonts, french

Thank you for your effort in answering my last question @Touhami. That question and the answer you gave are for a whole document. My next goal is to type a particular alphabet say 'M' using French Script MT font style in a document with a different font style. In particular, I want to use it in a formula. How do I go about it please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268426/how-to-write-in-french-script-mt-font

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, using `lualatex` or `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\newfontfamily{\frmtfont}{French Script MT}
\newcommand{\frmt}[1]{{\frmtfont #1}}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla \frmt{M} and bla bla bla
\end{document}
```